# Connect the image pairs

Tags: visual

Figure out the rule that groups the images into pairs and connect them with straight lines. The answer is a single word.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The connection is

> that some of the images are "double" other images. For instance, in the top right we have comic character TINTIN; at the bottom, we have TIN.

The completed drawing, with all images identified:

> [image]

Then,

> the uncrossed letters read EXTINCT BIRD: given the theme of doubled words, this must refer to the DODO! So the answer to the puzzle is **DODO** (or perhaps **DO**).